# Having difficulty resolving a circular dependency problem when including a windows header

Tags: c++, circular-dependency, c++-winrt

I am new to using COM interfaces, and there's one method in particular that I would like to call in my cppWinRT app:

[`ICompositionGraphicsDeviceInterop::GetRenderingDevice()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt620066.aspx)

The first problem I am having is what appears to be a circular dependency problem when I try to add `#include <windows.ui.composition.interop.h>` into my `pch.h`, which currently looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <unknwn.h>
#include <restrictederrorinfo.h>
#include <hstring.h>

#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.h"
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h>

#include "winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h"
#include <windows.ui.composition.interop.h>
```

I get the following compiler error:

> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.17744.0\winrt\windows.ui.composition.interop.h(100): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I tried to figure out which type is causing the problem, but I can't figure out which one at line 100 of `windows.ui.composition.interop.h` is problematic.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does line 100 of `windows.ui.composition.interop.h` look like?

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information.  At a guess, there a type (or macro) definition that is being used in the offending line, that is defined in another header.     That header needs to be included before `#include <windows.ui.composition.interop.h>`.   If it isn't, that will explain your problem.    The solution will then be to identify the other header and include it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed to know. I had an intuition that the problem probably had to do with the macro somehow. I had to include "combase.api.h". I'll update my question with that information.

Answer (score 1):

There was a macro at line 100, which required me to include "combaseapi.h".